# UIActivityIndicatorView proper usage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

My question regards the use of activity indicator in an iPhone project.
I have a class that contains an UIActivityIndicatorView

```
@interface StatusView : UIView 
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
    UILabel *textLabel;

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame Text:(NSString*)text andShowIndicator:(BOOL)value;
```

In my business logic code I call [indicator startAnimating] and the frame appears at the bottom of the screen. The code also contains a dealloc method that releases the indicator

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    [indicator release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Most of the time the indicator works well, however there are a few occasions that never disappears.

Do I always need to explicitly call the stopAnimating method? Does the release handle it?
What is the proper usage?

Comment: Set the indicators hidesWhenStopped to YES. You have to call the stopAnimating method each time you want it to stop.

Comment: does it stop automatically somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stopAnimating:` method stops the wheel of `UIActivityIndicatorView` and `release` release the object.
In Objective-C each object has an internal counter that is used to keep track of all references used by the objects or object has. `[object retain]` increments the counter by 1 and `[object release]` decrements the counter by 1. When counter reaches to zero, dealloc is then called. `release` is about memory management while `stopAnimating:` is a functionality of `UIActivityIndicatorView`.
So if you want to stop animating your `UIActivityIndicatorView` you would have to call `stopAnimating:` method. In **ARC** dont have to do `release` so better to use `ARC`.

Answer (score 0):

the best way when you are using this object is stopAnimating when you want to stop, remove from super view ( [activityObject removeFromsuperview] ) and finally release it. [ activityObject release];